# Math: Creating a curve with a steeper increase in value and longer ease in

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, curve, tween

I love this on article on ['how to lerp like a pro'.](https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/)... It has an excellent section on curves.

I'm currently increasing a number (min 0, max 180) by using this simple equation

```
float angleDifferenceCurved = (angle * angle);
```

This is what it currently should plot like (correct me if I'm wrong!)
[image: curveup]

However! I'd really like it if I could do something more like this

[image: steeper]

Thanks very much for any advice / code!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming problem.

Comment: Any number of functional forms could do it.  For example, simply changing to a higher-degree polynomial would work (e.g. `angle * angle * angle`).

Comment: I've removed the C# tag as it seems to be offending Servy (the language used is C# however). Thanks for the advice John, i'll give it a go. I was look for quite a big lead in with lower values though, so its not a perfect curve.

Comment: @Jim you could do angle^(5/2) or any other powers to suit your problem

Comment: Hey MisterSpock (great name!). Would I be able to use `float angleCurved = Mathf.pow (angle, 5/2);` in Unity? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Pow.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the useful replies

using this code

```
float angleCurved = Mathf.Pow (angle, 6/2.5f);
```

and this website with a thing to [draw function graphs](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) (really useful for visualising my problem!) I was able to piece something together.